# Is "moonstruck adventure" an actual term/expression?

Tags: expressions, questions

Encountered the phrase "moonstruck adventure" repeatedly in a text i'm dealing with (in the context of bad decisions made by someone that nearly led to disastrous results) - is that a proper term or expression? Because I've never heard it before and couldn't even find it online...

Comment: Hi @Tom can you please provide a reference for the text you are studying. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Webster's definition of moonstruck:

a. Affected by the influence of the moon; lunatic

Moonstruck is used with numerous nouns: Moonstruck love, A moonstruck summer... Always with the sense of lunacy,

So a moonstruck adventure would be a crazy adventure. But "moonstruck adventure" is not a genre in itself.

Answer (score 1):

"Moonstruck" means crazy, from the theory that the moon somehow controlled human behavior.  Moonstruck people were also called lunatics, from *luna*, the Latin word for moon.  In *Paradise Lost*, John Milton lists the maladies attributed to original sin, including

> Demonic phrenzy, moping melancholy
>   And **moonstruck** madness, pining atrophy

As one [explicator](http://by%20'%20moonstruck%20madness,'%20that%20kind%20named%20lunacy,%20from%20the%20supposed%20effect%20of%20the%20changes%20of%20...) notes, Milton means "by 'moonstruck madness,' that kind named lunacy, from the supposed effect of the changes of the moon on those afflicted with it."

Comment: Relevant: http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=lunacy&searchmode=none